# Why Firefox always display "Restart to Update"

Tags: firefox

Why does my Firefox always display "Restart to Update" even though it's the latest version?

[image]

When I clicked on that, it just restarted and nothing happened, and the button's still there.

This problem first appeared in `Firefox 16`. Back then the same thing happened and when I clicked on the button, it just restarted and didn't update, so I had to manually download the setup file for `Firefox 17` and install it manually

Comment: Try http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this method as per Mozilla Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939179)

> Please try this, ideally from an Administrator account: Search for all
>   instances of updates.xml, right-click each instance > Open file
>   location, check if it's related to Firefox and delete it along with
>   the whole updates folder which would be usually present in the same
>   location.